# Testing viewmodel constructor arguments with Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq

I have a basic CRUD application written in ASP.NET Core, with an example controller action looking like so:

```
public IActionResult Sheet(Guid characterId)
{
    var character = _repository.GetCharacter(characterId);
    // omit validation for brevity
    return View("Sheet", new ViewModel(character, true, true));
}
```

And an example unit test:

```
[Fact]
public void TestSheet()
{
    // Arrange stuff and mock setup
    // Act
    var result = _controller.Sheet(characterId) as ViewResult;

    // Assert
    Assert.NotNull(result);

    // assert ViewModel constructor called with x arguments
}
```

Other research seems to suggest having a mock of the object, but that would not be appropriate for this scenario.
I could simply have the constructor for `ViewModel` set a couple of getter properties, but that would seem to be delving into the realm of testing `ViewModel` as opposed to the controller. The controller should not care about what the ViewModel does with the values that are passed to it, and in my opinion neither should the test - the test is testing that the controller behaves properly, and should really only test that it is passing the correct values. A couple of getter properties would certainly achieve this but it just seems conceptually wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action is tightly coupled to the creation of the view model and this can be inverted

```
public interface IViewModelFactory {
    T CreateNew<T>(params object[] args) where T : ViewModelBase;
}

public class ViewModelFactory : IViewModelFactory {
    public T CreateNew<T>(params object[] args) where T : ViewModelBase {
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), args);
    }
}

public class ViewModelBase { }
```

so that it is not the responsibility of the controller to create/initialize view models. This will be an explicit dependency injected into the controller and used to create the view models.

```
public IActionResult Sheet(Guid characterId) {
    var character = _repository.GetCharacter(characterId);
    // omit validation for brevity
    return View("Sheet", _viewModelFactory.CreateNew<ViewModel>(character, true, true));
}
```

And desired behavior can be asserted when exercised in unit tests

```
[Fact]
public void TestSheet() {
    // Arrange stuff and mock setup
    var factory = new Mock<IViewModelFactory>();
    factory.Setup(_ => _.CreateNew<ViewModel>(It.IsAny<object[]>()))
           .Returns((object[] args) =>
               new ViewModel((Character)args[0], (bool)args[1], (bool)args[2])
           );      

    // Act
    var result = _controller.Sheet(characterId) as ViewResult;

    // Assert
    Assert.NotNull(result);

    // assert ViewModel constructor called with x arguments
    factory.Verify(_ => _.CreateNew<ViewModel>(It.IsAny<Character>(), true, true), Times.AtLeastOnce());
}
```